# Is it worth handling SEO friendly URLs that might change over time? Or should I use generic ones that will not change?

Tags: seo, url, googlebot, pagerank, url-slug

I will use SEO friendly URL slugs for my website pages.

But I would like to know how far should I go down this road.

My specific question is about whether I should be choosing SEO friendly URL's that might change over time.

**EXAMPLE:**

**From:** `/blog/top-3-tablets-for-2019`

This might need to change to (infact this example would change at least 1 time per year, because of the year change, but the number of products could also change):

**To:** `/blog/top-5-tablets-for-2020`

**QUESTION**

Is it worth the trouble? Because everytime that slug changes, I will need to manually set up a `301` redirect from the OLD to the NEW one. This is so I don't lose page ranking from Google. Otherwise Googlebot will see a `404` from the OLD one and will treat the new URL as a brand new page.

What I could be doing:

`/blog/best-tablets`   // <---- THIS WILL NOT CHANGE

And I'd still be able to update the page title:

From: `Top 3 tablets for 2019`
To: `Top 5 tablets for 2020`

So, should I take the trouble of updating the slug (at least once every year), or should I come up with generic slugs that should not change over time. Is there an SEO benefit on taking the more complicated route?

Comment: So, the plan is to always overwrite the same page with the latest information - the page is not static for very long? I guess that is the nature of your page and the user knows that is the case? You have no desire to create an archive of "Best X for 2020", "Best X for 2019", etc.? Which could have a combined SEO benefit? From a user's perspective, when I bookmark a "Best X for 2019" page I generally expect that information to remain relatively static and it to always show 2019 products. I also like to look at previous years products when looking for a budget purchase. (?) Just my 2c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - these "generic" slugs you mentioned are called "evergreen" URLs and you should use them - in your case, something like:

```
/blog/top-tablets
```

Adding the year to the URL can make it a bit clearer to the visitor but I would say that is redundant in most cases (and not necessary for SEO).